# OWASP Dependency Tracker Jenkins Plugin - Connection Refused

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed the Dependency tracker plugin in Jenkins but when I'm trying to configure it and test the connection, it is giving an error, and an error message is also not clear to me.

error message:

```
Connection failed
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474)
```

[image]
[image]

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the plugins homepage?

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/dependency-track/

Comment: used this link to install and configure dependency track plugin

Comment: Do you have an instance of Dependency-Track running? Does the "Dependency-Track  URL" point to this instance?

Comment: Yes, I'm running dependency track via container and it is running.

Comment: Jenkins and dependency container running locally.  Jenkins on localhost:8080 and dependency track on localhost:9090

Comment: The error message you posted in the screenshot might cut off some important HTTP response code inside the stacktrace, can you append this as a text-copy instead of a screenshot? (I mean the full stacktrace)
If there are subsequent lines starting with "Caused", please don't forget them.

Comment: sure, let me do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242490/discussion-between-rukender-and-cyberbrain).

Comment: @cyberbrain The link to your discussion is dead. Can you tell me how you both solved the issue in the end? I'm also running both Jenkins and DT in Docker and have the same problems.

Comment: We didn't find a solution in the chat, @Doesbaddel. It looked like the Dependency-Track was not reachable from Jenkins.

Comment: Ok, thx for the reply. Meanwhile, I tried the solution of Paul and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Is both Jenkins and Dependency-Track running as a container?

If so, setting the Dependency-Track URL to http://localhost:9090 will result in Jenkins attempting to connect to port 9090 on its local container.

You can try setting the Dependency-Track URL to use the IP address of the docker network interface. (e.g. http://172.17.0.1:9090)

See https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-connecting-containers-to-host.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me with the same problem. I used `ipconfig /all` on Windows respectively `ifconfig` on Linux to find the ethernet-interface of docker and the corresponding ip adress. The connection check is successful now!